# How do I fix this error code in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to use R Markdown for the first time and I keep getting an error code that says is occurring in the line with "library(knit)".

````
```{r setup}
library(knitr)
source("analysis.R")
```
````

The error code I keep getting is:

```
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source"): trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> install.packages -> contrib.url Exacution halted
```

Anybody know where I should go from here?

Answer (score 0):

I think it gives you the line where the block starts not the line with the error.

Without much more to go on, I'd be suspecting the source.  What happens when you run that block?

What happens if you open R from the command line and source it ?

It appears something is trying to install something...

Comment: And check the ``` is on a clean line not the end of the source line

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I had an "install.package" line in my R.analysis that was preventing me from knitting.